# Why is this question considered opinion based?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This question essentially has a yes/no answer. From responses so far it seems like the answer is 'no', and the only way it could be 'yes' is if someone has  specific knowledge about NuGet processes that I do not have, which would be objective and verifiable information. I can't see where opinion comes into it.

[How can I be sure that an unofficially uploaded NuGet package is genuine?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340715/can-i-be-sure-that-an-unofficially-uploaded-nuget-package-is-genuine)

Comment: possibly related: [Question closed because yes/no answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773) and  [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Comment: I think that yes/no discussion is irrelevant - it's clearly the knowledge for the justification of the answer that I'm looking for rather than the binary conclusion. A technical question about NuGet that many others will find useful isn't really customer support. I have to say this level of rather questionable pedantry over semantic analysis of a useful and well-worded question is probably putting a lot of people off from participating here.

Comment: these are your words not mine: "This question essentially has a yes/no answer"

Comment: Indeed, the ultimate conclusion of the answer will either be 'yes' or 'no', but the question is such that an unqualified 'yes' or 'no' is clearly not what is being asked for. The important point is that any explanation would have to be specific and objective, not opinion based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All it took was a few minor edits to make the question into something that could be reopened.

First, I changed the yes/no to an explicit how/why question. It may not seem like it's important, but it is. A question that is clearly asking how/why tends to attract better answers. Questions that ask yes/no questions tend to attract drive-by answers that don't explain how or why. Having a title that is a yes/no question attracts low quality answers and it's easier to put a question on hold than to monitor answers.

Second, I removed a question inside the body that asks about what NuGet does. We aren't technical or customer support for someone else's product, so we can't answer what they do or don't do. Also, their policies may change at any moment in time, so it helps to ensure that answers stay more relevant if we don't get into organizational policies and rules.